# how i can use Authorize attribute in ASP.NET MVC application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, authentication

i have a MVC application who have their own authenticate system. he used their own system and check the user by cookie parsing everytime.

how i can put the attribute Authorize on the action wherever i have information about the current user.

the user type is a enum who have a part of struct user {}

can anyone show me how i can use authorize attribute in my application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `AuthroizeAttribute` either on the Controller level:

```
[Authorize]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    // Now all actions require authorization
}
```

or Action level:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // Does not require authorization
    }

    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult PrivateThing()
    {
        // requires authorization
    }
}
```

You can pass usernames, roles, etc to the [`AuthorizeAttribute` constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.aspx) as well for finer grained authorization.

If, however, the default `AuthroizeAttribute` doesn't work for you you can always roll your own by inheriting from `AuthorizeAttribute`:

```
public CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute 
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext) 
    {            
        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);

        // Auhtorization logic here
    }
}
```